# Feedback diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to create a feedback diagram similar to [image]

I managed to get the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{
        block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
            minimum height=1cm,
            minimum width=2cm},
        input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
        output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=4cm},
        arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
        pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
        sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
    }
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {};
            \node [block, below=of input] (nn) {Neural Network};
            \node [block, below=of nn] (error) {Cost of the error};
            \node [input, right=of error, name=out] {};
            \node [block, below=of error] (opt) {Optimiser};
            \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {Input} (nn);
            \draw [draw,->] (out) -- node[xshift=1.75cm, yshift=0.3cm] {Actual output} (error) ;
            \draw [->] (nn) -- node {Calculated output} (error);
            \draw [->] (error) -- (opt);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

But as you can see, the left part is still missing and I haven't been able to create an arrow with text in such a way. How would I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that you are new to TikZ. I recommend using simple way to draw. A simple figure should be drawn by a simple way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={
        text=white,
        fill=red!70!black,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=3cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,red!70!black]
\path
(0,0)       node[block] (N) {Neural Network}
++(-90:2.5) node[block] (C) {Cost of the error}
+(-90:2)    node[block] (O) {Optimizer};

\draw[<-] (N.north)--+(90:.5) node[above,black] {Input};
\draw[->] (N)--(C) node[midway,right,black] {Calculated output};
\draw[<-] (C.east)--+(0:.5) node[right,black] {Actual output};
\draw[->] (C)--(O);
\draw[<-] (N)--++(180:3) coordinate (A)--++(-90:5.5) coordinate (B)-|(O);
\path (A)--(B) node[midway,left,align=left,black] {New weights\\and constants};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

**Update 1.** You can change arrows by putting `>=stealth` as an option of the tikzpicture. Arrows in Zarko's answer seems to be the most good looking ^^

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,red!70!black,>={Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 2]}]
```

[image]

**Update 2.** In case one doesn't remember options in library `arrows.meta`, then an user-defined arrow is also convenient. Here I designed an arrow named **meme**, with color cyan, using `pic`. I see that option `[sloped, pos]` is very nice for this purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
block/.style={text=white,
    fill=brown,
    minimum height=1cm,
    minimum width=3cm},
meme/.pic={% my favourite arrow
    \draw[teal] (150:6pt)--(0,0)--(-150:6pt);}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,brown]
\path
(0,0)       node[block] (N) {Neural Network}
++(-90:2.5) node[block] (C) {Cost of the error}
+(-90:2)    node[block] (O) {Optimizer};

\draw ([yshift=.5mm]N.north)--+(90:.5) pic[pos=0,sloped,xscale=-1]{meme}
node[above,black] {Input};
\draw (N)--(C) pic[pos=1,sloped]{meme} 
node[midway,right,black]{Calculated output};
\draw ([xshift=.5mm]C.east)--+(0:.5) pic[pos=0,sloped,xscale=-1]{meme}
node[right,black]{Actual output};
\draw (C)--(O) pic[pos=1,sloped]{meme};
\draw (N)--++(180:3) coordinate (A) pic[pos=0,sloped]{meme}
--++(-90:5.5) coordinate (B)-|(O);
\path (A)--(B) node[midway,left,align=left,black] {New weights\\and constants};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have just added an user-defined arrow using `pic`.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{
        block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
            minimum height=1cm,
            minimum width=2cm},
        input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
        output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=4cm},
        line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {};
            \node [block, below=of input] (nn) {Neural Network};
            \node [block, below=of nn] (error) {Cost of the error};
            \node [input, right=of error, name=out] {};
            \node [block, below=of error] (opt) {Optimiser};
            \begin{scope}[line]
            \draw (input) -- node {Input} (nn);
            \draw (out) -- node[xshift=1.75cm, yshift=0.3cm] {Actual output} (error) ;
            \draw (nn) -- node {Calculated output} (error);
            \draw (error) -- (opt);
            \draw (opt.south) |- ++ (-6em,-1em) |- (nn)
            node[pos=0.25,left,align=left]{New weights\\ and constants};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I have changed your code as little as possible as follows:

1) To get the same color as in your example, I used Stefan Trost's free [pipette tool](https://www.sttmedia.com/pipette):
And with the xcolor package I define the same color:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{149, 55, 53}
```

2) the block has a minimum width of `3 cm`

```
block/.style = {draw, rectangle,fill=myred,text=white,
            minimum height=1cm,
            minimum width=3cm}
```

3) to draw an arrow to the block `(error)`, I first place a `node` to its right and then an arrow with the `edge` syntax

```
\node[right=of error]{Actual output}edge[->](error);
```

4) for the arrow that goes around, I place an auxiliary `node (aux)`

```
 % auxiliary node (aux)
            \node [coordinate,below left=4mm and 10 mm of opt](aux){};
```

and use the syntax `|-` and `-|` in order to draw square lines. I place the text at `position 0.25`

```
\draw [->](opt)|-(aux)|-node[pos=.25,align=left]{New weigths \\and constant}(nn);
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{149, 55, 53}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{
        block/.style = {draw, rectangle,fill=red,text=white,
            minimum height=1cm,
            minimum width=3cm},
        input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
        output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=4cm},
        arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
        pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
        sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
    }
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {};
            \node [block, below=of input] (nn) {Neural Network};
            \node [block, below=of nn] (error) {Cost of the error};
            \node[right=of error]{Actual output}edge[->](error);
            %\node [ right=of error, name=out] {};
            \node [block, below=of error] (opt) {Optimiser};
            % auxiliary node (aux)
            \node [coordinate,below left=4mm and 10 mm of opt](aux){};
            \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {Input} (nn);
            %\draw [draw,->] (out) -- node[xshift=1.75cm, yshift=0.3cm] {Actual output} (error) ;
            \draw [->] (nn) -- node {Calculated output} (error);
            \draw [->] (error) -- (opt);
            \draw [->](opt)|-(aux)|-node[pos=.25,align=left]{New weigths \\and constant}(nn);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Voting down deserves an explanation. Without explanation this has no meaning other than gratuitous hostility.

Answer (score 9):

One more example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
 start chain = going below,
block/.style = {fill=orange!70!black, text=white,
                minimum height=8mm, minimum width=32mm,
                on chain},
arrow/.style = {draw=orange!70!black, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 2]}, thick},
every pin edge/.style = {arrow}
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (in)                      {Input};
    \node [block, below=of in] (nn) {Neural Network};
    \node [block,
           pin=right:Actual output
           ] (error)                {Cost of the error};
    \node [block] (opt) {Optimiser};
\coordinate[below=4mm of opt] (out);
%
\draw[arrow]    (in)    edge    (nn)
                (nn)    edge["Calculated output"]  (error)
                (error) edge    (opt)
                (opt.south) -- (out) -|
                ([xshift=-5mm] nn.west) node[pos=0.75,left,align=left] {New Weights\\ and constants}
                        -- (nn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]